# How to add listener to table column

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add listener to the `html` table column So that when I click the so called visualized `table column`, I want to perform something using `js`. consider this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Guga</td>
            <td>Nemsitsveridze</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Giorgi</td>
            <td>Beshidze</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when I click the `lastname` cell (I mean the one of the following elements: `<th>lastname</th>`, `<td>Nemsitsveridze</td>`, `<td>Beshidze</td>`) I want to perform something using `js`.

The solution I was thinking about is to assign some kind of `class` attribute to each element of the  `lastname` cell and add the same `event listener` to them independently, but I'm not sure if it is the only solution to this problem.

If anyone has an idea how to achieve this goal, please, answer the question.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to execute something when a column is clicked, you can add one event listener to the whole table and then check which column was clicked, then execute some code.

Using `window.event.target.cellIndex` you can access the cell index.

Using `window.event.target.parentNode.rowIndex` you can access the row index.

```js
document.getElementById('myTbl').addEventListener('click', function(event) 

{
  var col = window.event.target.cellIndex;
  var row = window.event.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
  if (col==1){
        alert('Col index is: ' + col + '\nRow index is: ' + row);
  }
});
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>lastname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Guga</td>
            <td>Nemsitsveridze</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Giorgi</td>
            <td>Beshidze</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```